# filesystem is unknown

Tags: boot, usb, grubrescue

I have a formated HDD in my acer notebook--`fat32`

I want to install Ubuntu from my USB stick but it doesn't want to boot from stick, also i can't see the USB stick in BIOS but my HDD is formated so i think it doesn't matter, it will go eventually to USB stick

I tried with Debian, and a different stick, same result

The result

```
error:unknown filesystem

Entering rescue mode...

grub rescue>
```

Bear with me, I've read all the related questions and the proposed solutions doesn't work

so, the next step is

```
    grub rescue>ls

    (hd0) (hd0,msdos1)(hd1)(hd1,msdos2

)
```

`hd0` is my formated HDD inside notebook

so Ubuntu is on `hd1`

but

`ls` (hd1,msdos2) gives me filesystem is unknown.

and this is the answer for all my sticks with Ubuntu, Debian.

what can i do next?

Comment: do you have another computer? ... it seems like your laptop isn't capable of booting from a USB. I would try the USB on another computer if possible and see if the other computer will boot to it ... if so ... your laptop may not have the capability and you will have to find a different way .. maybe using the CDRom instead.

Comment: yes, the usb flash drive is ok but the notebook doesn't have a cdrom

Comment: how old is the laptop ... most modern ones should boot to a usb .. but if its older .. it may not have that functionality

Comment: is not old, 2 years, acer aspire E 11 E3-112-C60G

Comment: and you say if you look in bios you dont see the USB showing up when its plugged in? .. sorry just trying to clarify

Comment: it's ok, thank you for your time, i have tried with four different usb flash, and they don't show up; also i tried to modify boot order but with no effect

Comment: yeah i see there is an issue with it ... or a simular one .. probably has something do to with uefi but im not really good with that `https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/396264/aspire-e3-111-p605-f12-does-not-show-usb-boot`

Comment: you may look into this `https://www.vanstechelman.eu/content/creating-an-uefi-bootable-linux-usb-stick`

Comment: my BIOS it s stuck on Legacy, i have tried to change it to UEFI, just to try it out, but it doesn't work

Comment: are you using rufus ..  and that is stuck on legacy? hmm ... :) let me see if i can figure out why that is happening

Comment: not rufus, unetbootin for creating usb drive

Comment: i would give rufus a try and see if you can make a uefi boot `https://rufus.akeo.ie/` sorry im not familiar with unetbootin but I have created uefi boots with rufus .. worth a shot I guess :) sorry i coudlnt be more help

Comment: i tried with USB flash made with rufus, no result; maybe is a problem with my BIOS? can I do something about it?

Comment: sorry i dont really know UEFI stuff that well .. you may look into [Installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) there are things you need to change in the UEFI/BIOS